# How to convert binary data from SQL table (check if its image type) and display it on Winforms C#

Tags: c#, sql, binary

I'm trying to read data from SQL Server with binary, Check if file type is image and then display it in Windows Forms using C#. I have searched solution during two days I found some good examples but they not works for me, Here is my code below:

```
public byte[] byteArrayIn { get; set; }
    public Image img { get; set; }
    public Image convertImage(string id)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Doc_Invoice FROM Repairs WHERE ID ="+id, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
            byteArrayIn = (byte[])reader["Doc_Invoice"];
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        {
            if (IsValidImage(byteArrayIn))
            {
                img = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        return img;
    }
    public static bool IsValidImage(byte[] bytes)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And I'm calling this method from another form like

```
picRequest.Image = db.convertImage(id.ToString());
```

Guys only one question, What is wrong with my Code? :(
[image: Here is SQL Result]
[image]

Comment: You haven't told us why you think your code is wrong.

Comment: What is error message and which line is failing?  The data may be stored as a 64 Base String and you need to convert.  Or the image may be a format that you PC graphic card doesn't support.   Look at stream and see if character have diamonds and question marks which would indicate binary.  If all the character are readable than you have a Base 64 String (not a binary image).

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working"? Do you get an error? Does your code run, but no image is displayed? When you debug your code step by step are all the values set as expected, are you getting a record back from the database etc? Also, **[use parameterised queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)**, and you should use [Pascal Case for properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

Comment: @jdweng I understood your answer, but I have tried already with base64 String to convert this img. result is same

Comment: -ReadTimeout 'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' int {System.InvalidOperationException}
I think this is the main problem

Comment: The error message indicates it cannot convert the data in the memory stream to an image.  So did the convert from base64 string work?   Usually if data was not base64 string you would of gotten an exception.  So I'm assuming the conversion worked.  After  writing the base64 string to the memory stream did you set the position of the stream to zero  before trying to convert.  This is a very common issue.  Most people forget (even me occasionally).

Comment: @jdweng I hope I made that error while converting on Base64, I will try it again and I hope you are right :) Thank you anyway

Comment: @jdweng There is no Base64 involved here. He reads the data as binary (byte[]) and not string, and going by the SSMS screenshot the data is stored binary (BLOB).

Comment: @churi : Are you sure.  Reading ALL the response.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I got answer I think, I need to know your answers as well
So the binary data that I stored into my SQL Server was store from MS Access (OFFICE 365)
so
I think MS Access added his Header to the picture while converting IMG To Binary

What you think? Or if someone can help me to find how much byte uses MS Access for Header?
I will start reading IMG byte starting after Access's Header like:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes,[MS Access Header byte],bytes.Length - [MS Access Header byte]))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
```

Comment: That is it. I was right. I find header size of 252 byte and I use that code 
var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes,252,bytes.Length - 252)
now it works but different type files has different offset :(